# Sharepoint и WebService.asmx

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint

Можно ли в приложение asp.net для Sharepoint 2013 добавить [WebMethod] ?
Добавил ссылки на System.Web и Sytem.Web.Services, но все равно выдает ошибку что пропущена директива на сборку..

Comment: Читайте внимательно SOAP. У меня работает. Библиотеки перечислю.

Comment: Библиотеки System.Web.Services,  System.Web.UI, System.ComponentModel. В references подключено System.Web, System.Web.Extention, System.Web.Services

Comment: Там ещё нужно web.config правильно настроить

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Подскажите что нужно сделать с web.config..